# dragging and dropping components onto a window in java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a network simulator that allows a user to build network models by dragging and dropping components onto a window and then connecting them together. Please any idea on how i can achieve this in java

Comment: you should edit your question and precise the java technology used for the  presentation layer  ? Swing ? JSP ?  JSF ?etc...

Comment: @davidhxxx I do not know what java technology to use as I am a beginner in ava programming. How would you recommend I go about this

Comment: The first question is so : On which support do you want that your application  runs? Desktop app  ? Web Browser app ?  Smartphone app ?

Comment: @davidhxxx it is a desktop application, I have been able to implement a drag mouse adapter on the JLabels representing the various network devices. on clicking any of these labels, a new label that looks like the one clicked upon is created, given a mouseMotionListener and added to a JPanel . However when added to the JPanel, they do not appear on it unless I set a Layout manager and the problem with this is that it does not allow a user drag the labels into any arbitrary positions of his/her choosing.